# PhoneGap and Nexus S?

Tags: javascript, cordova, nexus-s

I am testing the getPicture API to get a picture from gallery.

I wrote this :

```
        navigator.camera.getPicture(
        this.onSuccess, 
        this.onFail, 
        {
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
            sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
            allowEdit: false,
            mediaType: Camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
        }
```

Then, I get :

**can't open '/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.myapp/cache/Pic.jpg'**

I think PhoneGap try to put the cache in sd card by default. My "Google Nexus" don't have any.

Someone got the same issue ?

**[EDIT]**

I've got this permission in my Manifest, but it does not change anything :

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: please check is SD Card exist or not

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the following permission in your AndroidManifest.xml?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```